# Preventing Of Re-Rendering Child component Through UseSelctor state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am passing useSelector state from parent to child whenever parent is re-render child component is re-rendering where useSelector data is not changed,here is my code.

```
const Header = () => {
  const response = useSelector((state) => state.dataReducer);
  return response && response.data ? (
    <>
      //code...
      <Child iconColor={response.data.icon.color} />
    </>
  ) : (
    ""
  );
};


const Child = ({ iconColor }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    //code...
    console.log(1);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ color: iconColor }}>//code...</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

whenever Header component is re-render, I can see child is re-rendering.How to solve this?

I have tried with adding React.memo() in child component, but not worked, here is my code,

```
const Child = React.memo(({ iconColor }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
  //code...
    console.log(1);
  },[]);

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{color : iconColor }}>
      //code...
      </div>
    </>
  )
});
```

Comment: Children components always re-render when their parent does, this is how react works. Memoizing is the correct method to prevent this. However, when memoization comes up it's always worth asking: do you really need to? Unless the Child component is causing noticeable performance problems by re-rendering, you really shouldn't pre-emptively memoize components

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes I really need to.

Comment: adding memo on child component that not worked.

Comment: We'll need more info in order to determine why React.memo did not work for you. Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre]. What are you using to determine that the component re-rendered?